# Android App Testing

Tags: android

I want to change the orientation of the device, setRequestedOrientation works when changeConfig="orientation" is not included. 
But if my app uses this configuration please suggest a way.

Also, it would be preferable if this can be done via the Command line adb (and on a device not on an emulator )

Comment: "changeConfig="orientation" is not included" means included in your manifest ?
"But if my app uses this configuration" ... sorry, but what does it means ?

Answer (score 0):

This is used to set the layout  Orientation

AndroidManifest ->application->screen Orientation.

Go to AndroidManifest select the application tab the select ,the activity you want to  set Orientation  in the right side there is an option screen Orientation select it as your need.

Comment: i want to change the orientation of the device[android amazon devices] from the adb command. i have been trying couple of things but nothing seems to work also tried...                        service call window 18 i32 1  Also i tried to use getevent and sendevent they work on some devices and doesnt work on others [ the orientation change events are not at all caught in certain devices by the getevent call]